# Using Interface via WCF and directly

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvm, prism, async-await

I have a business Layer that implements a given Interface, with a WCF service that has no implementation and simply uses the Interface as the contract. It routes down to the BL concrete class:

**BL Layer**

```
public interface IClass1
{
    List<int> GetData();
}

public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    public List<int> GetData()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**WCF Service**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="BusinessLayer.Class1" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="BusinessLayer" %>
```

On my client side, I have an MVVM Prism module containing a service class implementing IClass1. The idea, is that I could build my solution containing the service module (to communicate with the DB via the service) or containing the BL project directly (in which case it would communicate directly to the DB).

This seems to work pretty well, but I want to enable the use of async-await within my application. Normally I'd just call the WCF Service method using the `<method>Async` call, and have it pass back the Task. However I get errors when doing this, basically telling me my service module implementation needs to return `Task<List<int>>` when using await.

Because there is only a single interface between the BL, the service layer, and the service module, this means modifying the Interface itself to return the Task, but I'd rather the WCF Service was able to return either `List<int>` (when called synchronously) or `Task<List<int>>` when called via the Async method.

Is there any way to achieve this without having a separate interface for the WCF Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "asynchronicity" of a WCF server is completely independent from its client proxy.

So, I think changing the interface is the correct approach.

- `IClass1.GetDataAsync` would return `Task<List<int>>`.
- The WCF service implementation would return `Task<List<int>>`, and likely be `async`.
- Re-create your WCF proxy. This will create a `Task<List<int>> GetDataAsync()` as well as a `List<int> GetData()` on the proxy.

Comment: I assume in point one you meant `IClass1.GetData` would return `Task<List<int>>`, rather than `GetDataAsync`. To be honest this confused me for a while, but having just done it. I discovered that even though `GetData` returns a task, the WCF implementation of it strips off the Task - then creates a `GetDataAsync` task as normal to manage the task return.

Comment: I would change the name of `GetData` to `GetDataAsync` on the interface; this is the [pattern for `Task`-returning methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). The WCF proxy will create both `GetData` and `GetDataAsync`.

Comment: Fair point. I'll do that then. Didn't realise that the WCF would do it in either direction to be honest. Thats good to know.